# How do I add parameters to the following stored procedure call?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

How do I add parameters to the following stored procedure call?

```
using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
using (var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn) { 
                           CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure }) {
   conn.Open();
   command.ExecuteNonQuery();
   conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Have you explored command.Parameters?

Comment: Since you have a `using` block you don't need to call `conn.Close();` explicitly.

Comment: do yourself a favor and stop using ado.net directly, there are many options available, http://abstractsql.codeplex.com if you can't use C#4 features, where you could use Dapper, Massive, Petapoco, etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@number", TextBox1.Text)

Happy coding!!

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
// this would work for a varchar or nvarchar parameter
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourParameter", "someValue");
// this would work for an integer parameter
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@someInt", 1234);
```

Obviously you need any code to add parameters to the `Parameters` collection *before* you try to call `command.ExecuteNonQuery();`.

Answer (score 1):

I thing you need to be more specific.

What is the problem with using `command.Parameters.AddWithValue` ?

Answer (score 1):

This might be a solution:
This parameter should be the exact name of the parameter from your stored procedure("yourParameter").

`using (var conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))

 {

     var command = new SqlCommand("ProcedureName", conn){CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure };

command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@yourParameter", "someValue");

conn.Open();

   command.ExecuteNonQuery();

   conn.Close();

}`

Answer (score 1):

```
command.Parameters.Add(
        new SqlParameter("@customerId", custumerId));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [SqlCommand.Parameters Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters.aspx).

```
command.Parameters.Add("@SomeParmeter", SqlDbType.Int); //SqlDbType is enum
```

Answer (score 0):

For more details go thru this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx

below code is copied from the above posted link

```
static void GetSalesByCategory(string connectionString,string categoryName)
{
    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        // Create the command and set its properties.
        SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand();
        command.Connection = connection;

        command.CommandText = "SalesByCategory";       
        command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        // Add the input parameter and set its properties.
        SqlParameter parameter = new SqlParameter();
        parameter.ParameterName = "@CategoryName";
        parameter.SqlDbType = SqlDbType.NVarChar;
        parameter.Direction = ParameterDirection.Input;
        parameter.Value = categoryName;

        // Add the parameter to the Parameters collection. 
        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);

        // Open the connection and execute the reader.
        connection.Open();
        SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                Console.WriteLine("{0}: {1:C}", reader[0], reader[1]);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No rows found.");
        }
        reader.Close();
    }
}
```